# What is difference between Where and Join in linq?

Tags: linq, join, where-clause

What is difference between of these 2 queries ? they are completely equal ?

```
from order in myDB.OrdersSet
    from person in myDB.PersonSet
    from product in myDB.ProductSet
    where order.Persons_Id==person.Id && order.Products_Id==product.Id
    select new { order.Id, person.Name, person.SurName,  product.Model,UrunAdı=product.Name };
```

and

```
from order in myDB.OrdersSet
    join person in myDB.PersonSet on order.Persons_Id equals person.Id
    join product in myDB.ProductSet on order.Products_Id equals product.Id
    select new { order.Id, person.Name, person.SurName,  product.Model,UrunAdı=product.Name };
```

Comment: why did you label the question as "entity-framework"? maybe you are using linq in entity framework but this is a general linq question not ef.

Comment: Yes, i thought what u have said.I am not expert and i have never used joining in normal linq queries when i start to learn Entity framework i saw it and thought that join method can dependenices on EF.Now i understand it is not EF question so i am removing that tag now.

Answer (score 5):

The end result should be the same.

But using `JOIN` is clearer - it's more obvious what you're doing (joining three sets of data).

My personal "best practice" approach would be:

- use `WHERE` to reduce and limit the number of rows returned - it's typically limiting one set of data (by defining some criteria to be met)
- use `JOIN` to express the intent of joining two tables / sets of data together on a common field (or set of fields)

Answer (score 1):

Join shows the relationship between table clearer and also in less keystrokes.

Comment: This goes well with the LINQ philosophy: prefer code clarity to execution speed. Especially when there is no speed loss in the clearer code, of course :-)

Comment: These clarity can cause such questions as i asked.Because if where does all job of join so what is difference between of them .If there is no difference so why join is exist : )

Comment: the clarity is, when you use join, you use a higher abstraction. however, "where" is its underlying implementation. also, this is not linq's style of having where and join. it is because sql has both of them.

Comment: Join has restriction for Table relationships when "where" hasn't.This would create problems. Join only accept "Equals" operator while "where" support many logical operators.